# What's the mobileish connect url of Facebook connect?

Tags: facebook

I use the following URL setting to authorize Facebook login. But the page for Application Authorization is webish, and not mobileish.

```
webview
        .loadUrl("http://www.connect.facebook.com/login.php?return_session=1&nochrome=1&fbconnect=1&extern=2&connect_display=popup&api_key="
                + FConnect.API_KEY
                + "&v=1.0&next="
                + FConnect.SUCCESS_URL
                + "%3Ffb_login%26fname%3D_opener&cancel_url="
                + FConnect.CANCEL_URL
                + "%23fname%3D_opener%26%257B%2522t%2522%253A3%252C%2522h%2522%253A%2522fbCancelLogin%2522%252C%2522sid%2522%253A%25220.741%2522%257D&channel_url="
                + FConnect.XD_RECEIVER);
```

As you see this is webish, as I had to scroll to the middle,

[alt text http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/2100/facebookconnect.png](http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/2100/facebookconnect.png)

Do you know the address to get a mobileish App authorization page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Facebook developer [wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authentication_and_Authorization_for_Facebook_for_Mobile_Applications), it says that you have to set your display parameter to "wap" if you're on the mobile.

I guess you would have to check if the user is on a mobile or a PC. If on a mobile, change the display parameter to "wap", else keep it to "pop-up".

Comment: I used `m.facebook.com/tos.php` from the same URL and does work well now.